# Cannot connect to running container getting error wait until the container is running

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I build this minimal `Dockerfile` ends up size 1.18mb

```
FROM prom/blackbox-exporter
ENTRYPOINT ['/bash']
COPY config.yml /etc/blackboxexporter/config.yml
```

Using the command

```
docker build -t "blackbox:dockerfile" .
```

Now I wanted to run so I ran with `-idt` flag:

```
docker run -idt  --restart unless-stopped  -p 9115:9115 --name blackbox blackbox:dockerfile
```

but now when I try to enter the docker container I still can't enter and I get the error

Wait until the container is running.

Answer (score 1):

Given the error you mentioned, I would suggest replacing the single quotes by double quotes:

```
FROM prom/blackbox-exporter
ENTRYPOINT ["/bash"]
COPY config.yml /etc/blackboxexporter/config.yml
```

Reference: https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/30752